# jQuery: apply effect to each element in a jquery collection with a pause

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection returned by $('.line'). It has 6 elements and I want them to get hidden and then appear from first to last, where a line starts appearing only when the one before it has completed it's animation.

```
function animateLines(lines) {
       lines.toggle(function(){});
           lines.each(function(i, line){
                setTimeout( $(this).toggle(function(){}), 3000);
            });

}
```

This makes the lines disappear all at one and then appear all at once. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just change the timeout parameter that you pass into `setTimeout`. You'll also need to pass a function to `setTimeout` instead of immediately calling `toggle`.

Try this:

```
function animateLines(lines) {
   lines.toggle();
   lines.each(function(i, line){
       setTimeout(function(){ $(line).toggle(); }, 3000 * (i + 1));
   });
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/6yTER/)